# Python disfunctional after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, python3

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL) and somehow my Python is all messed up.

When I load Ubuntu, I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory

$ type python python3
-bash: type: python: not found
-bash: type: python3: not found
```

However, these exist:

```
$ type python3.10 python3.11
python3.10 is /usr/bin/python3.10
python3.11 is /usr/bin/python3.11
```

I installed `python-is-python3`. I thought this was supposed to take care of all of this for me (and that Ubuntu 22.04 was supposed to preinstall Python3). How do I fix this? I could, e.g., `alias` `python` and `python3` to one of these installs, but that doesn't seem like the right solution, and moreover apparently `pip` (which somehow does exist) is explicitly trying to run `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 has python 3.10. Have you installed 3.11 yourself?

Comment: @RA I think when python3 didn't exist I manually installed 3.11 thinking that no python existed, then I found 3.10. But why is it so incompletely set up?

Comment: Remove WSL and reinstall latest WSL with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Would that wipe the data I have on there now?

Comment: /usr/bin/python is normally a link to /usr/bin/python3.10 , as is /usr/bin/python3.  Just remake them.

Comment: Yes, but you can always take a backup of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[update-alternatives](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) might solve your problem

(below is just the output on my system, it will look different at your side....)

```
$ update-alternatives --config python
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.10        0         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10        0         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.11        0         manual mode
  3            /usr/local/bin/python3.9   0         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

First do this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep python
```

On my system it shows:

```
pybabel                        auto     /usr/bin/pybabel-python3
python                         auto     /usr/bin/python3.10
sagenb-export                  auto     /usr/bin/sagenb-export-python3
```

This meant that you need `python` (and not `python3`) as paramter after `--install`.

So, when 3.10 is not in the list after `--config` do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.10 0
```

Comment: Luuk ... OP seems to be missing a default python3 version link in the alternatives system ... Therefore, I guess `sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 0` is needed first.

Comment: ... and maybe `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3` as well.